# negating np.isnan in np.where

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have two numpy arrays, I want to throw away all entries with nan entries in both list. How do I do this? (nan can only occur in the first list)

I have tried the following:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,2,np.nan,3,4])
b = np.array([5,6,7,8,9])
```

If I do:

```
b[np.where(np.isnan(a))]
```

this returns me:

```
np.array([7])
```

However, I want

```
np.array([5,6,8,9])
```

I tried several different ways of negating the np.where using np.logical_not and ~, but I have not managed to get this to work.

Comment: Skip the `np.where`. Play around with those `not`.

Comment: thanks. that solves it. when is np.where needed?

Comment: Follow the docs, much better coverage there than comments could cover here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need negation `~` right before `np.isnan`; `np.where` return indices where the conditions are true and it's not easy to negate *indices* since negative index has special meanings (*extract elements from the end of sequence*) in python:

```
b[~np.isnan(a)]
# array([5, 6, 8, 9])
```

The following works as well (though not necessary):

```
b[np.where(~np.isnan(a))]
# array([5, 6, 8, 9])
```